# Run time analysis

Tags: java, loops, runtime

I wanted to know the general run time of these 2 separate programs. I've been struggling with method of computing them.

problem 1

```
y = 0.5;

for (j = 0; j < N; j = j + y) {
  operation();
  y = 2*y;
}
```

problem 2

```
s1 = 1;
s2 = 1;
for (i = 1; i <= N; i++ ) {
  for (j = 0; j < s2; j++) {
    operation();
  }
  x = s1 + s2;
  s1 = s2;
  s2 = x;
}
```

Comment: What's the run time of `operation()`?  If that's "O(1)" or "O(n^2)", it makes a big difference.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java